# Equation of tangent line for $y' = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ at point $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I tried to solve this by plugging zero into x the $x$ values and I end up getting $\frac{0}{1}$, which obviously is $0$. From there I multiply out and get all zeros. What am I doing wrong? More importantly, what do I not understand?

Comment: So the tangent line is $y = 0$?

Comment: Is $y'$ the derivative of the function $y$, for which you need the equation for the line tangent to $y$ at $(0, 0)$?

Comment: Yeah. The original function was $y= \frac{x}{1-x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the equation of the line tangent to $y$ at $(0, 0)$ and you have found $y'$, then the slope of the tangent line is zero at $(0,0)$. That means the desired line is horizontal, and the equation of the desired line will have the form $y = c,\;\;c\text{ is a constant}.$

In this case, your equation will be the horizontal line given by $$y-0 = 0(x-0) \iff y = 0$$

**ADDED:** I see in your comment that the original function is $y = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$. If so, then your derivative $y'$ is incorrect. You should have $$y' = \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

And further, the slope of the line tangent to $y$ at $(0,0)$ will be $1$. (Just evaluate the derivative at $x=0$.) Can you take it from here?